# Running MVC Web app targeting .net 4.6.1 in a virtual directory under a ASP.NET core web app. Is it possible?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've converted my personal website from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core Web app (.net framework).  I've uploaded this to azure app services and works fine.

I would now like to run my blog (which is a ASP.NET MVC web app targeting .net 4.6.1) in a virtual application called Blog.

Is this possible and if so what steps do I need to take?

More info. I've tried using web deploy in VS to deploy the blog app to the virtual directory.  <del>However, though it says successful the blog folder is not present under wwwroot.</del>.  My mistake the blog is present in /site/wwwroot.  However, I get a HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when accessing the sitename.com\blog.

Comment: Not an answer but i gave up on this and ended up having a new app service for my blog so rather than www.mysitename.co.uk/blog, i now have blog.mysitename.co.uk.  Not an answer sorry but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer in the question below fixes the issue that I had.

[ASP.NET 4.5 throws 502.5 as a virtual application in Azure Web App under a ASP.NET Core 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103786/asp-net-4-5-throws-502-5-as-a-virtual-application-in-azure-web-app-under-a-asp-n)

Answer (score -1):

You can crate the Virtual Application in the Azure web apps by adding the path to  the Folder in the Virtual Directories and Application section under App Settings.

[image]

Comment: I've done this already.  But im asking about deploying a ASP.NET MVC to a virtual app running under a ASP.NET Core web app.

Comment: You can deploy in normal way the only difference between ASP.NET MVC and ASPNET  CORE app is the Libraries using which it is build and since all the libraries are placed separately for each application in bin folder. You can run application easily under ASPNET core app.

Comment: Have you done this on windows azure?  Run an ASP.NET MVC as a virtual app under ASPNET Core?

Comment: I haven't tried but i am sure it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. hence the question.