# ASP.NET 4.5 throws 502.5 as a virtual application in Azure Web App under a ASP.NET Core 2.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

This IS a duplicate from "[Running MVC Web app targeting .net 4.6.1 in a virtual directory under a ASP.NET core web app. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182794/running-mvc-web-app-targeting-net-4-6-1-in-a-virtual-directory-under-a-asp-net)" but it is not resolved and OP said he solved it by creating an additional app. So I post it again.

I have an Azure Web App organized as follows:

```
"site/wwwroot/MyWeb.dll" (ASP.NET Core 2.0)
"site/admin/MyAdmin.dll" (ASP.NET 4.5)
```

The web works ok. But when I try to access the admin site I get the following error

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

The following is an extract from **".../logFiles/eventlog.xml"** which I thought was useful

```
<Event>
        <System>
            <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module"/>
            <EventID>1000</EventID>
            <Level>1</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-04T20:09:05Z"/>
            <EventRecordID>1024919046</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>RD00155D77CB9A</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYAPP/ADMIN' with physical root 'D:\home\site\admin\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\MyWeb.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008081.</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
```

Feel free to ask for any kind of info you may need.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYAPP/ADMIN' with physical root 'D:\home\site\admin\' failed to start process with **commandline 'dotnet .\MyWeb.dll'**, ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008081.

It seems that your virtual application targets on ASP.NET 4.5 is served by the `AspNetCoreModule` module. You could modify the `web.config` file under your ASP.NET 4.5 application as follows:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/> <!--add this line-->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Details you could follow [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Also, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286281/stop-web-configuration-inheritence-with-azure-virtual-web-application/).